# For loop does not check every object property

Tags: javascript

I have a problem where my code doesnt check all storage object barcodes. I want it to check all bolts, brackets, screwdriver and hammer barcodes and check it with input one, if its the same then show the corresponding object. But it only works for the last one always. I have no idea what is causing this. Row amount is how many inputs there is (you can click a button to add new input) inputs have name input1 input2 input3... so on...

```
var storage = {
  bolts: {
    barcode: 57263144,
    price: 0.5,
    name: '100mm Bolts',
    stock: 8642,
  },
  brackets: {
    barcode: 13245627,
    price: 0.2,
    name: 'Plain Brackets',
    stock: 5201,
  },
  screwdriver: {
    barcode: 52678349,
    price: 15,
    name: 'Screwdriver',
    stock: 30,
  },
  hammer: {
    barcode: 86583916,
    price: 25,
    name: 'Hammer',
    stock: 5,
  }
}

function check(){
  Object.keys(storage).forEach(function(key) {
    for (var i = 1; i <= rowAmount; i++){

      var barcodeCheck = document.getElementById("input"+i).value;

      var input = document.getElementById("input"+i).value;

      if (input.length > 8){
        document.getElementById("input"+i).style.backgroundColor = "red";
      }
      else {
        document.getElementById("input"+i).style.backgroundColor = "white";
      }


      if (barcodeCheck == storage[key].barcode){
        document.getElementById("name"+i).innerHTML = "Name: "+storage[key].name;
        document.getElementById("price"+i).innerHTML = "Price: £"+storage[key].price+" / one";
        document.getElementById("stock"+i).innerHTML = "In stock: "+storage[key].stock;
      }
      else {
        document.getElementById("name"+i).innerHTML = "";
        document.getElementById("price"+i).innerHTML = "";
        document.getElementById("stock"+i).innerHTML = "";
      }
    }
  });

  setTimeout(check,1);
}
check();
```

Comment: what is `rowAmount` and where is it defined?

Comment: rowAmount is how many inputs there is (i have a button that adds new input) each new input is called input1 input2 input3 ...

Comment: Please include a [mcve]. The Minimal part for this question would include the `rowAmount` as @Craicerjack mentioned, and the HTML upon which the code runs. As a side note, you close out your `check` function with a call to `check` again in 1 millisecond. That could cause some serious issues with the responsiveness of the page.

Comment: I can link you entire code if you want.

Comment: That value is pretty irrelevant. If not having rowAmount defined determines whether or not you can answer this question then I don't think you understand the problem.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/zh2nvkp1/  this is my entire code.

Comment: I figured it out, the else statement was changing everything back to nothing. Everything else was fine. Thank you for trying though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is [for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in).

You also have this function to run pretty much constantly. 1ms is far too tight a poll and your application's performance is going to suffer.

**UPDATE**: The real culprit here, as I discovered (and as the answer below pointed out) is that after you've check a key and appropriately manipulated the DOM, you then continue checking. The subsequent checks will obviously fail, because there's only one right answer, and then everything gets reset.

To clarify, looping through the keys using forEach is not an incorrect solution, though using `for...in` is cleaner and more appropriate to the task at hand.

```
var storage = {
  bolts: {
    barcode: 57263144,
    price: 0.5,
    name: '100mm Bolts',
    stock: 8642,
  },
  brackets: {
    barcode: 13245627,
    price: 0.2,
    name: 'Plain Brackets',
    stock: 5201,
  },
  screwdriver: {
    barcode: 52678349,
    price: 15,
    name: 'Screwdriver',
    stock: 30,
  },
  hammer: {
    barcode: 86583916,
    price: 25,
    name: 'Hammer',
    stock: 5,
  }
}

function check(){
  var match = false;

  for (var key in storage) {
    for (var i = 1; i <= rowAmount; i++) {
      //barcodeCheck and input had the same value
      //I also removed the .value. You'll see why in a sec
      var input = document.getElementById("input"+i);

      if (input.value.length > 8) {
        input.style.backgroundColor = "red";
      }
      else {
        input.style.backgroundColor = "white";
      }

      if (input.value == storage[key].barcode){
        document.getElementById("name"+i).innerHTML = "Name: "+storage[key].name;
        document.getElementById("price"+i).innerHTML = "Price: £"+storage[key].price+" / one";
        document.getElementById("stock"+i).innerHTML = "In stock: "+storage[key].stock;

        match = true;
      }
    }

    if (match) break;
  }

  //Only reset if you've checked them all and come up short
  if (!match)
  {
    document.getElementById("name"+i).innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("price"+i).innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("stock"+i).innerHTML = "";
  }

  //Nobody's going to notice a 250ms delay in your poll
  setTimeout(check, 250);
}
check();
```

Comment: Doesnt work, https://jsfiddle.net/zh2nvkp1/ this is my entire code, the problem is when i type in barcode only last one in storage (hammer in this case) is showing, rest items doesnt show.

Comment: oh i forgot to add jquery to fiddle.

Comment: Fixed. You need to end execution once you find a match.

Comment: I dont know why it still doesnt seem to read the other values. It doesnt read the barcode 13245627 for example, but it should.

Comment: Your fiddle has other problems. I'm trying to test my solution, so please stand by.

Comment: I never used jsfiddle, http://codepen.io/killerek/pen/PbYrRm?editors=0010 this is my original.

Comment: I've updated my answer. This should fix your problem.

Comment: Im sorry for having a big bug, but it doesnt show any values now, i think its because it looks through object but not from actual barcodes but only loops the bolts, brackets etc.

Comment: I figured it out, the else statement was changing everything back to nothing. Everything else was fine. Thank you for trying though.

Comment: If you read the answer you'll see that I addressed that problem. I tested that code in your fiddle, and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are only seeing the last one be correct is your for loop is going though each iteration and checking to see if the input matches one of the stored values and not stopping running though the for loop when it finds a match.

```
function check(){
outer_loop:
Object.keys(storage).forEach(function(key) {
for (var i = 1; i <= rowAmount; i++){

  var barcodeCheck = document.getElementById("input"+i).value;

  var input = document.getElementById("input"+i).value;

  if (input.length > 8){
    document.getElementById("input"+i).style.backgroundColor = "red";
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById("input"+i).style.backgroundColor = "white";
  }


  if (barcodeCheck == storage[key].barcode){
    document.getElementById("name"+i).innerHTML = "Name: "+storage[key].name;
    document.getElementById("price"+i).innerHTML = "Price: £"+storage[key].price+" / one";
    document.getElementById("stock"+i).innerHTML = "In stock: "+storage[key].stock;
break outer_loop; //This will end the for loop and allow the found values to stay instead of over writing them on the next loop iteration and jump out of both loops
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById("name"+i).innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("price"+i).innerHTML = "";
    document.getElementById("stock"+i).innerHTML = "";
  }
}
});
 setTimeout(check,1);
}
check();
```

UPDATE:

Below is the fixed code that'll do what you are looking for.  You were going after the keys first which you should have been going after the input boxes first then trying to match them to the keys.  Sorry for the multiple updates.

```
<style>
input {
  float: left;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 24px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: width cubic-bezier(0.92,0,0.29,0.99) 0.6s;
  font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
  font-weight: 900;
  clear: both;
}

.red {
  color: red;
}

* {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 800;
}

#table > div {
  border: 2px solid black;
  float: left;
  width: 300px;
  padding: 5px;
}

input[type=number]::-webkit-inner-spin-button, 
input[type=number]::-webkit-outer-spin-button { 
  -webkit-appearance: none; 
  margin: 0; 
}

.clear {
  clear: both;
}

button {
  background-color: orange;
  border: 2px solid black;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  font-size: 14px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.4s;
}
button:hover { 
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: yellow;
  transform: translateY(2px);
}


</style>

barcodes: 13245627, 57263144, 52678349, 86583916 <br>
<input type=number id=barcode placeholder=Barcode>
<div id=output></div>
<div id=test></div>
<button onclick=newRow();>New row</button>
<button onclick=deleteRow();>Delete last row</button><br><br>
<div id=table></div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>

<script>
var storage = {
  bolts: {
    barcode: 57263144,
    price: 0.5,
    name: '100mm Bolts',
    stock: 8642,
  },
  brackets: {
    barcode: 13245627,
    price: 0.2,
    name: 'Plain Brackets',
    stock: 5201,
  },
  screwdriver: {
    barcode: 52678349,
    price: 15,
    name: 'Screwdriver',
    stock: 30,
  },
  hammer: {
    barcode: 86583916,
    price: 25,
    name: 'Hammer',
    stock: 5,
  }
}
var rowAmount = 0;

function display(){
  var barcode = document.getElementById("barcode").value;
  var numbers = [];
  var sum = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < barcode.length; i++){
    numbers[i] = barcode.charAt(i);
    if (i === 0 || i === 2 || i === 4 || i === 6){
      numbers[i] = numbers[i] * 3;
    }
    sum += parseInt(numbers[i]);
  }

  var nearestWhole = Math.ceil(sum/10)*10;

  var lastDigit = (nearestWhole - sum);

  var isRight = false;

  if (barcode.length === 8 && nearestWhole - sum === 0){
    isRight = true;
  }

  document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = numbers+"<br>Sum: "+sum+"        <br>Is right: "+isRight+"<br>Last digit: "+lastDigit+"<br>Nearest whole:     "+nearestWhole;

  if (barcode.length > 8){
document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "INVALID";
    isRight = false;
  }    
  if (isRight === false && barcode.length > 7){
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "<span class=red>Invalid     barcode</span>"
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "";
  }

  setTimeout(display,1);
}
display();

function newRow(){
  rowAmount++;
  var elem5 = '<div id=cellNumber'+rowAmount+'>';
  var elem = '<div class=clear></div>';
  var elem1 = '<div id=cell'+rowAmount+'><input type=number placeholder=Barcode id=input'+rowAmount+'></div>';
  var elem2 = '<div id=name'+rowAmount+'></div>';
  var elem3 = '<div id=price'+rowAmount+'></div>';
  var elem4 = '<div id=stock'+rowAmount+'></div>';
  var elem6 = '</div>'
  $('#table').append(elem5+elem+elem1+elem2+elem3+elem4+elem6);
}
function deleteRow(){
  if (rowAmount === 1){
    document.getElementById("input1").value = "";
  }
  if (rowAmount > 1){
    $('#cellNumber'+rowAmount).remove();
    rowAmount--;
  }
}

function check(){


//Object.keys(storage).forEach(function(key) {
outer_loop:
for (var i = 1; i <= rowAmount; i++){
    for(var z=0; z < Object.keys(storage).length;z++){
        var key = Object.keys(storage)[z];

          var barcodeCheck = document.getElementById("input"+i).value;

          var input = document.getElementById("input"+i).value;


          if (input.length > 8){
            document.getElementById("input"+i).style.backgroundColor = "red";
          }
          else {
            document.getElementById("input"+i).style.backgroundColor = "white";
          }


          if (barcodeCheck == storage[key].barcode){
            document.getElementById("name"+i).innerHTML = "Name: "+storage[key].name;
            document.getElementById("price"+i).innerHTML = "Price: £"+storage[key].price+" / one";
            document.getElementById("stock"+i).innerHTML = "In stock: "+storage[key].stock;
            break; //This will end the for loop and allow the found values to stay instead of over writing them on the next loop iteration
      }
      else {
            document.getElementById("name"+i).innerHTML = "";
            document.getElementById("price"+i).innerHTML = "";
            document.getElementById("stock"+i).innerHTML = "";
      }
    }
  }

  //Nobody's going to notice a 250ms delay in your poll
  setTimeout(check, 250);
}
check();

newRow();
</script>
```

Comment: I made that mistake as well. This fix only breaks the *inner* loop, so it will check the next key and reset anyway.

Comment: Ah i missed the outer loop.

Comment: I updated my answer to include the outer_loop name position to break to once you get the required data.

Comment: I figured it out, the else statement was changing everything back to nothing. Everything else was fine. Thank you for trying though.